# Vue not loaded in test (cucumber/capybara)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, vuejs2, cucumber

I'm testing my RoR application containing vue objects with cucumber.
All is well in the browser, but in tests vue isn't loaded. I tried to increase waiting time for capybara, but it didn't work. Please point me somewhere.

I get this:
[image: here is how the page looks in test]

The code I want to test is

```
#student_profiles.nomargin
  = render "header"
  .container-fluid.nopadding
    .student_count.aside-wrap.rounded-corners
      %text v-bind:students-count="studentsCount"
      %p.text Sie können aktuell aus <b>{{studentsCount.count}}</b> 
      Schülerinnen und Schülern aus bis zu 50 Ländern wählen.</p>
    .filters.aside-wrap
      %h4 Verfeinern Sie Ihre Auswahl durch Filtern: <filters :filters="filters" :filter-params="filterParams" :load-limit="loadLimit" :students="students" :counter="counter" :hobbies="hobbies" :update="update" :filter-loaded="filterLoaded"></filters>
      %br
      %text v-bind:students-count="studentsCount"
      %p.text Es werden <b>{{studentsCount.count_filter}}</b> von <b>{{studentsCount.count}}</b> angezeigt.</p>
      %br
```

Steps i use are:

```
@javascript
Scenario: Happy path to bla-bla
  Given I am on a mobile device
  Given I have '6' students shown in the app
  And I visit 'url'
  And I wait for the ajax request to finish
  Then I should see "6" within ".student_count"
```

For the step `Given I have '6' students shown in the app` i have following step definition.

```
Given(/^I have '(\d+)' students shown in the app$/) do |student_count|
  student_count.to_i.times do
    student = FactoryBot.create(:ib_student)
    FactoryBot.create(:ib_student_profile, student: student, force_profile_visible: true)
  end
end
```

Comment: what webdriver are you using? some basic googling seems to suggest that you may need to use the [chrome headless drivers](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/headless-feature-specs-with-chrome) although that probably also means [phantom](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) would work and I would generally recommend phantom since it does not need a true browser to run

Comment: I use poltergeist for default headless tests, and selenium for non-headless tests. Strange, that tests of another app with vue pass

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me was switching our whole test suite to Selenium headless-chrome instead of Poltergeist/Phantom JS.